# jQuery UI Tabs plugin can't handle 2 tiers of tabs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a legacy project that uses jQuery UI tabs to display user generated data in a structured way. The system does not cap the number of tabs a user can create (but usually there are about 30 in the second tier) and jQuery UI Tabs just wraps the tabs, which looks very unprofessional.

[image: Wrapping tabs in my project.]

I stumbled over Paul Blundell's beautiful plugin [OverflowTabs](https://github.com/paul-blundell/OverflowTabs) from 2014 (here is his JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o1wLbtj4/, ), but unfortunately I can't get it to work right with my 2 tiers of tabs. I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.4.
[image: Gathered tabs in a dropdown menu in Paul Blundell's JSFiddle.]

I've made a simplified JSFiddle which shows what I'm trying to do: open a dialogue window that contains data in 2 tiers of tabs. When there are too many tabs, both tiers are supposed to push overflowing tabs into a menu that opens a dropdown when clicked, but at the moment (on the tier with names) only the last tab is displayed and the dropdown button doesn't work and reads 0: http://jsfiddle.net/megahra/6s2xwgec/18/

As far as I can tell the plugin properly removes tabs from the first tier and adds them to the overflow div (_hideTab function), but for some reason later this is overwritten. I suspect that the plugin can't deal with the second tier properly, but I don't know where to fix that.

I'd be really grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction!

EDIT:
Thanks to Twisty's help the plugin now works for multiple tiers of tabs and I fixed a few bugs.
**Here is a working JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/megahra/uexr4qfw/289/
- Known bug: this plugin is not applied to tabs in divs with `style="display: none"` at time of initialization.

```
$.widget("ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {
  options: {
    overflowTabs: false,
    tabPadding: 25,
    containerPadding: 0,
    dropdownSize: 50
  },

  _create: function() {
    this._super("_create");
    this.tabsWidth = 0;
    this.containerWidth = 0;
    this.overflowTabsId = "id" + this._createUniqueId();

    $(this.element).addClass(this.overflowTabsId);

    if (!this.options.overflowTabs)
      return;

    // update the tabs
    this.updateOverflowTabs();

    // Detect a window resize and check the tabs again
    var that = this;
    var el = this.element;

    $(window).resize(function() {
      // Add a slight delay after resize, to fix Maximise issue.
      setTimeout(function() {
        that.updateOverflowTabs();
      }, 150);
    });

    // Detect dropdown click
    $(el).on("click", '> .overflow-selector', function(e) {
      $('> .ui-tabs-overflow', el).toggleClass('hide');

      $overflowTabs = $('.ui-tabs-overflow').not($('> .ui-tabs-overflow', el));

      //if there is more than the currently clicked one, close all others
      if($overflowTabs) {
        $overflowTabs.toggleClass('hide', true);
        }
    });

    //Detect tab click
    $('li a').on("click", function(e) {
        //close dropdown if open
        $('> .ui-tabs-overflow', el).toggleClass('hide', true);
        //ToDo: apply overflowTabs plugin to content of new tab (if it contains tabs)

    });
  },

  refresh: function() {
    this._super("refresh");
    this.updateOverflowTabs();
  },

  updateOverflowTabs: function() {
    var failsafe = 0;
    this._calculateWidths();
    var el = this.element;

    // Loop until tabsWidth is less than the containerWidth
    while (this.tabsWidth > this.containerWidth -10 && failsafe < 30) {
      this._hideTab();
      this._calculateWidths();
      failsafe++;
    }

    // Finish now if there are no tabs in the overflow list
    if ($('> .ui-tabs-overflow li', el).length === 0)
      return;

    // Reset
    failsafe = 0;

    // Get the first tab in the overflow list
    var next = this._nextTab();

    // Loop until we cannot fit any more tabs
    while (next.totalSize < this.containerWidth && $('> .ui-tabs-overflow li', el).length > 0 && failsafe < 30) {
      this._showTab(next.tab);
      this._calculateWidths();
      next = this._nextTab();
      failsafe++;
    }

    $('> .overflow-selector .total', el).html($('> .ui-tabs-overflow li', el).length);
  },

  _calculateWidths: function() {
    var width = 0;
    $(this.element).find('> .ui-tabs-nav > li').each(function() {
      width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    this.tabsWidth = width;
    this.containerWidth = $(this.element).parent().width() - this.options.containerPadding - this.options.dropdownSize;
  },
  _hideTab: function() {
    if (!$(this.element).find('> .ui-tabs-overflow').length) {
      $(this.element).find('> .ui-tabs-nav').after('<ul class="ui-tabs-overflow hide"></ul>');
      $(this.element).find('> .ui-tabs-overflow').after('<div class="overflow-selector">&#8595 <span class="total">0</span></div>');
      //calculate position of overflow-selector relativ to tab row (overflow-selector is 15px high)
      let topOffset = ($(this.element).find('> .ui-tabs-nav').innerHeight() * 0.48) - 12;
      $(this.element).find('> .overflow-selector').css('top', topOffset);
    }
    var lastTab = $('> .ui-tabs-nav li', this.element).last();
    lastTab.prependTo($('> .ui-tabs-overflow', this.element));
  },
  _showTab: function(tab) {
    tab.appendTo($('> .ui-tabs-nav', this.element));

    // Check to see if overflow list is now empty
    if ($(this.element).find('> .ui-tabs-overflow li').size() == 0) {
      $(this.element).find('> .ui-tabs-overflow').remove();
      $(this.element).find('> .overflow-selector').remove();
    }
  },
  _nextTab: function() {
    var result = {};
    var firstTab = $(this.element).find('> .ui-tabs-overflow li').first();
    result.tab = firstTab;
    result.totalSize = this.tabsWidth + this._textWidth(firstTab) + this.options.tabPadding;
    return result;
  },
  _textWidth: function(element) {
    var self = $(element),
      children = self.children(),
      calculator = $('<span style="display: inline-block;" />'),
      width;

    children.wrap(calculator);
    width = children.parent().width();
    children.unwrap();

    return width;
  },

  _createUniqueId: function() {
    // Math.random should be unique because of its seeding algorithm.
    // Convert it to base 36 (numbers + letters), and grab the first 9 characters
    // after the decimal.
    return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some legacy code usage and just did a bit of minor cleanup. I found a few issues.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/tbvasj1g/

1. Click Event was being greedy and was hiding list items that did not need to be hidden
2. Add/Remove class is pre-toggle method. Updated to use `.toggleClass()`
3. `.size()` is depreciated for `length`

   > Note: This method has been removed in jQuery 3.0. Use the .length property instead.
   >   The `.size()` method is functionally equivalent to the `.length` property; however, the `.length` property is **preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.**
4. `$(this.element).find(selector)` replaced with shorthand `$(selector, this.element)`.
5. Moved `.total` update out of the calculate function and into the update function. Something was resetting it back to `0` at the end of the loop. not sure what. It just didn't make sens to have that updated there so I moved it and it works now.

**Widget Factory**

```
$.widget("ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {
  options: {
    overflowTabs: false,
    tabPadding: 25,
    containerPadding: 0,
    dropdownSize: 50
  },
  _create: function() {
    this._super("_create");
    this.tabsWidth = 0;
    this.containerWidth = 0;
    if (!this.options.overflowTabs)
      return;

    // update the tabs
    this.updateOverflowTabs();

    // Detect a window resize and check the tabs again
    var that = this;
    var el = this.element;

    $(window).resize(function() {
      // Add a slight delay after resize, to fix Maximise issue.
      setTimeout(function() {
        that.updateOverflowTabs();
      }, 150);
    });

    // Detect dropdown click
    $(".tabStructure").on("click", ".overflow-selector", function(e) {
      $('.ui-tabs-overflow', el).toggleClass('hide');
    });
  },

  refresh: function() {
    this._super("refresh");
    this.updateOverflowTabs();
  },

  updateOverflowTabs: function() {
    var failsafe = 0;
    this._calculateWidths();
    var el = this.element;
    console.log("cWidth", this.containerWidth);

    // Loop until tabsWidth is less than the containerWidth
    while (this.tabsWidth > this.containerWidth && failsafe < 30) {
      //debugger;
      this._hideTab();
      this._calculateWidths();
      failsafe++;
    }

    // Finish now if there are no tabs in the overflow list
    if ($('.ui-tabs-overflow li', el).length === 0)
      return;

    // Reset
    failsafe = 0;

    // Get the first tab in the overflow list
    var next = this._nextTab();

    // Loop until we cannot fit any more tabs
    while (next.totalSize < this.containerWidth && $('.ui-tabs-overflow li', el).length > 0 && failsafe < 30) {
      this._showTab(next.tab);
      this._calculateWidths();
      next = this._nextTab();
      failsafe++;
    }

    $('.overflow-selector .total', el).html($('.ui-tabs-overflow li', el).length);
  },

  _calculateWidths: function() {
    var width = 0;
    $(this.element).find('.ui-tabs-nav > li').each(function() {
      width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
      //debugger;
    });
    this.tabsWidth = width;
    this.containerWidth = $(this.element).parent().width() - this.options.containerPadding - this.options.dropdownSize;
  },
  _hideTab: function() {
    if (!$('.ui-tabs-overflow').length) {
      $(this.element).find('.ui-tabs-nav').after('<ul class="ui-tabs-overflow hide"></ul>');
      $(this.element).find('.ui-tabs-overflow').after('<div class="overflow-selector">&#8595 <span class="total">0</span></div>');
    }
    var lastTab = $(this.element).find('.ui-tabs-nav li').last();
    lastTab.appendTo($(this.element).find('.ui-tabs-overflow'));
  },
  _showTab: function(tab) {
    tab.appendTo($(this.element).find('.ui-tabs-nav'));

    // Check to see if overflow list is now empty
    if ($(this.element).find('.ui-tabs-overflow li').size() == 0) {
      $(this.element).find('.ui-tabs-overflow').remove();
      $(this.element).find('.overflow-selector').remove();
    }
  },
  _nextTab: function() {
    var result = {};
    var firstTab = $(this.element).find('.ui-tabs-overflow li').first();
    result.tab = firstTab;
    result.totalSize = this.tabsWidth + this._textWidth(firstTab) + this.options.tabPadding;
    return result;
  },
  _textWidth: function(element) {
    var self = $(element),
      children = self.children(),
      calculator = $('<span style="display: inline-block;" />'),
      width;

    children.wrap(calculator);
    width = children.parent().width();
    children.unwrap();

    return width;
  }
});

$(function() {
  $("#rowDialog").dialog({
    title: 'Test modal',
    closeOnEscape: false,
    minHeight: 'auto',
    width: '600px',
    modal: true,
    resizable: true,
    buttons: [{
      // Close button
      text: 'Close',
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close')
      },
    }]
  });

  $(".tabStructure").tabs({
    overflowTabs: true
  });
});
```

Not a fan of this solution on a whole. I would advise pagination of the tabs. If there is no content in the other tabs or not a lot of content, the drop-down gets clipped. Also if you select a tab from the drop-down, it gets hidden and you have no good way to know which tab you're viewing, their is no visual indicator.

Comment: Thank you! :) I learned a lot from your answer. The reason I picked this solution instead of pagination of tabs is that the tab labels in my project include a status symbol and the user wants to be able to see all labels at once. As for the dropdown clipping: each of my numbered tabs contains a table, so I can guarantee enough content to prevent clipping. You make a good point regarding the visual indicator of the selected item in the dropdown. I'll definitely add that (like Paul Blundell has in his jsfiddle). But can you tell me why the plugin doesn't get applied to the second tier of tabs?

Comment: Which version of jQuery introduced the $(selector, this.element) shorthand? (Because our project still uses jQuery 1.10.2...)

Comment: Works for both tiers of tabs now. I ended up adding direct child  (>) to all the selector statements in the plugin, e.g. `$('> .ui-tabs-overflow li', this.element)`, to make sure the right tier was targeted. The plugin is still terribly buggy (I'm posting a new question), but if you add this to your answer I'll accept it. :) Thank you!

Comment: @megahra *Selector context is implemented with the `.find()` method; therefore, `$( "li.item-ii" ).find( "li" )` is equivalent to `$( "li", "li.item-ii" )`.* https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context

Comment: Yes thank you, I learned that from your answer. But the reason why all selectors need to be prefixed with the direct child selector (>) is that there could be multiple levels of tabs. Which leads to multiple overflow-selector buttons and multiple dropdown menu elements in the DOM at different levels. If you don't tell the plugin that you want the set of elements that are direct children of the node it was initialized on, it puts tabs into wrong containers, opens all dropdowns at once and does all kinds of unwanted behavior.